# Migrate speech profile

Tags: migration, voice-dictation, speech

I've been speaking into my Mac for the last couple of years.

I'm starting a fresh OSX.

If I understand correctly, the speech recognition improves over time.

Is it possible to migrate my old profile, so it doesn't have to learn from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming - and that's a big if - that your speech profile is user specific you could still try migrating but only migrating your home folder (e.g. via Time Machine or from Mac to Mac) instead of the full system.